# How can I reload the webpack when I changed one of my required modules in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, package.json

It is okey when I changed the .js files in the same directory.

But I have dependencies in package.json.
I didn't figure it out, is it possible the reload when I changed something in .js files one of these dependencies.

Comment: are you using node server or webpack-dev-server?

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran I am using webpack-dev-server.

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

you can use this `npm` command from package.json,

```
{
"build": "webpack --progress --color",
"watch": "nodemon --watch ./ --delay 200ms --exec npm run build"
}
```

You can use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) to watch files which are out of webpack context. But webpack `watch` wont work with this.

```
nodemon --watch ./ --delay 200ms --exec 'your cmd here'
```

The above command will watch the files under the root folder and will execute the command which will trigger the webpack build. Here no need of setting `watch` flag for webpack because `nodemon` is watching everything.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your replies. It is now okey , when we change .js files in node_modules.

Comment: If possible, I want to ask one more question. For example, I have 'A' folder in my root directory and I am requiring this A from another folder, let say B. Entering 'npm install' command in B. Folder A is coming to B's node_modules,as expected. I want also reload my webpack,when ı changed A folder files under the root, not B's node_modules's A. Thanks

Comment: For this kind of scenario, you could go with nodemon.json config file as shown [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md). You can use `ignore` property which accepts array of file paths in glob patterns